# List or discover methods that are not covered by an Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

I'm working as a "code reviewer" on a project.

It's a C# application, Visual Studio 2019, and I would like to know what methods are not covered by an Unit Test, but without check them one-by-one.

There is a way to list or discover all methods (or, at least, the public ones) that are not coved by an Unit Test?

Comment: Here you go -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019

Comment: Questions about tools are off-topic here, sorry.

Comment: @panoskarajohn this article shows many ways to know code coverage, and what "pieces" of code are not covered by an Unit Test, but don't show what methods don't have Unit Tests (like a report, I mean)

Comment: Also if you need sth more concrete there are tools CI/CD tools, which will provide you daily reports for how many test cases are failing and code coverage. This is out of  the scope of this question. .

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Code Coverage Results panel, inside visual studio.

Here you can see my results.

Which shows everything! Even how much coverage each method has.
Take a look at my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools which can help you cover code coverage for .Net.

Jetbrains dotCover is one such tool. It can integrate with Resharper unit test runner and can show which tests cover which code.

Additional info is available here: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/show-covering-test-with-dotcover/

Comment: There is no need for JetBrains...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019

Comment: There are many tools that show what methods _are covered_, but these tools don't show what method _are **not** covered_... That's the difficult I'm experiencing...

Comment: @panoskarajohn If one have the Enterprise edition, I'd daresay one shouldn't be here asking such a question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen this question is off topic to begin with. I just provided a functionality inside visual studio. There is no need to refer third party tools. Also the author never provided a visual studio version.